# How i can do bzr merge of a git repository into bazaar branch?

Tags: git, bazaar

I have tried get the change of github repository to one repository bazaar,

something like this:

> bzr merge git@github.com:Author/repository.git

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well this will work, but maybe clone the git repository, then convert it to a bazaar repo and then merge it.

I also see there is a plugin that may help: https://github.com/trobz/git-bzr-merge
"This plugin has been created to help merging GitHub OpenERP modules into Launchpad branches."

Answer (score 1):

You can if you have bzr-git installed. However, bzr only understands URLs, not rsync-like location identifiers. So for the location you specified, you would want to use:

```
bzr merge git+ssh://git@github.com/Author/repository.git
```